# processing: trouble using global array in if condition in for loop

Tags: java, conditional-statements, processing

I am trying to write a small program that has a given number of balls (in the example code below it's 3) travel back and forth across the screen at different speeds and phases (start offset).
This much has been achieved in the code. Although I want to be able to select the balls (one at a time) using a mouse click.
I have used the word "HIT!!!" to signify in the console that a ball has been clicked.

My problem is that when I run the code below, I only get a "HIT!" in the console when I click the top ball. That is when the first element y[0] matches with the click_Y variable. When I am sure (but obviously mistaken somehow) that there should be matches when I click in the vicinity of y[1] & y[2].

I'd really be grateful for any help with these. As it's gotten to the point where I am starting to stare blankly at the screen. Thanks.

```
int     noCircles;    // the number of items in the array (# of circles)
float[] y;      // y-position of each circle (fixed)
float[] speed;  // speed of each circle
float[] phase;  // phase of each circle

float red = 120;
float green = 120;
float blue = 120;

float click_X;
float click_Y;
void setup() {
  size(500, 500);

  noCircles = 3;

  // allocate space for each array
  y = new float[noCircles];
  speed = new float[noCircles];
  phase = new float[noCircles]; 

 // calculate the vertical gap between each circle based on the total number 
 // of circles
  float gap = height / (noCircles + 1);

  //setup an initial value for each item in the array
  for (int i=0; i<noCircles; i++) {
    y[i] = gap * (i + 1);
    // y is constant for each so can be calculated once
    speed[i] = random(10);
    phase[i] = random(TWO_PI);
  }
}
void draw() {
  background(155);

  for (int i=0; i<noCircles; i++) {
    // calculate the x-position of each ball based on the speed, phase and 
    //current frame
    float x = width/2 + sin(radians(frameCount*speed[i] ) + phase[i])* 200; 
    if (dist(x, y[i], click_X, click_Y) <= 20){
        println("HIT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }
    ellipse(x, y[i], 20, 20);
    click_X = 0;
    click_Y = 0;
  }
 }
void mousePressed() {
  println("You clicked******************************************");
  click_X = mouseX;
  click_Y = mouseY;
  println("click_X =" +  click_X);
  println("click_Y =" +  click_Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problems like these are best solved by [debugging](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) your program. Start by tracing through the code by hand, then add print statements (more than you've already added), and if that doesn't work then don't be afraid to use the debugger.

You're using the `click_X` and `click_Y` variables to check the position of the mouse against the position of each ball. Trace through the `for` loop in your `draw()` function. What happens at the end of the first iteration?

You reset the values of `click_X` and `click_Y`. That's why you aren't detecting any hits on the other circles.

You could probably refactor your code to only reset those variables if something has been hit, but really, I would stop using them altogether.

I'm guessing that you're using those variables because you only want to check when the mouse is pressed? Just use the `mousePressed` variable for that. Then you can use the `mouseX` and `mouseY` variables directly.

Then your `if` statement would look like this:

```
if (mousePressed && dist(x, y[i], mouseX, mouseY) <= 20) {
  println("HIT: " + i);
}
```

Also, using separate arrays like this is called parallel arrays, and is general a bad habit to get into. You should probably use [classes](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes I had some incline resetting Click_X and Click_Y had something to do with it. I had commented out those lines. Though without resetting those variables as was getting multiple "HIT"s for every time a ball crossed the point I had clicked, whereas I only wanted one hit per click. As you say though I while have to find another way to deal with this. Thank you for some very sound advice!!

Comment: I moved the lines 'click_X = 0;' and 'click_Y = 0;' down a few lines in the code so that they are outside of the for loop but they still get reset so that they don't "hang around" causing hits even though a ball has not been directly hit.       I know this is probably not best practice. But it has give me some relief and breathing room for now. I will refactor. Thanks again Kevin!

Comment: @HiSulu I've recommended that you get rid of those variables entirely. Just delete them. The `if` statement I posted shows you exactly what to do instead.

Comment: Using the suggested 'if' statement would allow to get rid of the click_x and click_y. Although using mousePressed is not ideal because it seems that it repeatedly calls while the mouse button is down. Triggering more than one event for even a very fast click. I just want one event to be triggered when clicking a ball. The for loop  is executed quickly enough that click_X and click_Y are reset before anything else can happen. I'm sure there's a way to get single hits registering w/out click_X and click_Y though. Cool website btw (http://happycoding.io/). Thanks again!

Comment: @HiSulu It's not the `for` loop that's causing your click detection to trigger multiple times. It's the fact that the `draw()` loop is called 60 times per second. To fix that problem, you could just move that whole loop into the `mousePressed()` function.